# How to trigger an event when plugin is closed/destroyed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have a CKEditor instance with custom plugins. I thought that when `CKEDITOR.instances[element.name].destroy(true)` is called it will call some kind of "destroy" events of all the plugins, but I couldn't find any [API reference](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.pluginDefinition) about such en event available for plugins.

How can I execute an event or function inside plugin that will contain special logic of cleaning things related to that plugin?

Comment: You can try to check if the element exists, if it doesn't then you execute your code. You will have to bind this though, probably to a change event in the html, body, since when the object is destroyed, it's bound to have some change event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CKEditor fires [`editor#destroy`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-destroy) event by default. Just put your cleanup logic into the callback:

```
editor.on( 'destroy', function() {
    // cleanup goes here
} );
```

There is no corresponding event for the plugins because there's no such need: all the plugins  die along with the editor (`editor.destroy()`). Always.